# Get number between characters in Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Having difficulty creating a regex. 
I have this text:
"L\":0.01690502,\"C\":0.01690502,\"V\":33.76590433"
I need only the number after C\": extracted, this is what I currently have.

```
        var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=C\\"":)\d +.\d + (?=\s *,\\)");
        var test = regex.Match(content).ToString();
        decimal.TryParse(test, out decimal closingPrice);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the number after `C\":`, you can capture `(\d+.\d+)` in a group:

[`C\\":(\d+.\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/K0801T/1)

You could also use a positive lookbehind:

[`(?<=C\\":)\d+.\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/K0801T/2/)

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work, returned an empty string in my code, worked on the website though.

Comment: @KrystianB I've updated my answer with a positive lookbehind. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to fetch all pairs of letter and number.

```
var regex = new Regex("(?<letter>[A-Z])[^:]+:(?<number>[^,\"]+)");
var input = "L\":0.01690502,\"C\":0.01690502,\"V\":33.76590433";
var matches = regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().ToArray();

foreach (var match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine($"Letter: {match.Groups["letter"].Value}, number: {match.Groups["number"].Value}");
```

If you only need only number from "C" letter you can use this linq expression:

```
var cNumber = matches.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Groups["letter"].Value == "C")?.Groups["number"].Value ?? "";
```

Regex explanation:

```
(?<letter>[A-Z]) // capture single letter
[^:]+ // skip all chars until ':'
: // colon
(?<number>[^,"]+) // capture all until ',' or '"'
```

Working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s3IWfg)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with this.

```
 var regex = new Regex("(?<=C\\\":)\\d+.\\d+(?=\\s*,)");
 var test = regex.Match(content).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

String literal to use for C#:

```
@"C\\"":([.0-9]*),"
```

If you wish to filter for only a valid numbers:

```
@"C\\"":([0-9]+.[0-9]+),"
```